# access denied loadLibrary java.lang.RuntimePermission java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, java-native-interface, applet

I need to implement smart card authentication for NHS as described here.
https://developer.nhs.uk/apis/spine-core/smartcards.html

i am getting following error.

access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.TicketApiDll")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.TicketApiDll")

I created sample applet and tried to execute. Applet is executing with class path of jar file as mentioned by NHS UK.

```
  import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import com.gemplus.gemauth.api.GATicket;
    public class AuthenticateExample extends Applet {

          public void paint(Graphics g)
          {
              try{
              String str = this.getParameter("msg");
              g.drawString("asdasdasdasdsad",200,80);   
              //g.drawString(str,100,80);   
              g.drawString(authenticate(),100,80);  
              }
             catch(Exception e)  
            {  
                System.out.println("Exception Aamir");  
                System.out.println(e);  
            }  
          }
          public String authenticate() throws Exception {
            GATicket gat = new GATicket();
            String ticket = gat.getTicket();
            return ticket;

        }

}
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> A Simple Program </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

Here is the output of my program:

<applet code="AuthenticateExample" ARCHIVE="GATicket.jar"  WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">
<PARAM name="msg" value="hi aamir love">
</applet> 
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i need token in result as mentioned in NHS web site.

EDIT

```
grant codeBase "file:///F:/Projects/Java/GATicket.JAR" {
      permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

it has been added as describe by other post.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719065/java-calling-dll-from-a-local-applet-im-doing-something-wrong

Comment: no its not , i have jar files which is complied by third party .. though i have given all permission its not working hence posted.